# Tried reading a parquet file in spring boot without using spark. It works in local machine but doesn't work when deployed on AWS ECS container

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, parquet

Getting this error:- `Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file file: localdirectory/samplefile.parquet`.

I have to read a directory containing parquet file from s3 bucket. For this, I am downloading the directory from s3 in local and reading it in stand alone java project. Below code is used for downloading...

```java
MultipleFileDownload multipleFileDownload = transferManager.downloadDirectory(bucketName, keyPrefix, directoryToSaveParquetFiles);
```

I, then tried to read parquet files from local directory.
Code used to read parquet file.

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("parquet.avro.readInt96AsFixed", "true");
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(new Path(filePath)).withConf(conf).build();
GenericRecord obj = reader.read(); 
while (obj != null) {
  //read attributes
  obj = reader.read();
}
```

Used maven dependency

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetReader;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

Used sdk in project

```java
11 Amazon Corretto version 11.0.11
```

Works perfectly fine in local machine(I'm using Intellij IDEA). But when deployed to AWS ECS, getting this error

```java
Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file file: localdirectory/samplefile.parquet
```

Comment: It is not a file... A `java.io.File` has to be a physical resource on the filesystem. It isn't it is loaded from a jar. Hence you need to use `getResourceAsStream` or `getResource` to load it.

Comment: I suggest you use Spark/Flink for reading parquet data from S3